# GLS, heteroskedasticity and Ridge Regression/Lasso

Tags: lasso, generalized-least-squares

I am hoping to use a regularised regression technique, using cross validation, to fit a linear model to a set of predictors which have some highly correlated variables.

However, I also know (highly suspect) that there is a significant amount of heteroskedasticity in the errors. I saw this question: [Ridge and LASSO given a covariance structure?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32682/ridge-and-lasso-given-a-covariance-structure), which suggests that if I know the variance structure it is easy to incorporate it into these procedures. However I do not, and instead was hoping to estimate it using a GLS or Feasible-GLS framework.

My initial thought is to run my CV-regression process with no variance model, estimate one from the residuals, scale and re-run the regression. However this feels very ad-hoc and I'd like to know if there is an obvious problem with this approach?